# Code Reordering by visual c++compiler

Tags: visual-c++, compiler-optimization

When the same piece of c++ code is compiled with the same version of visual c++ compiler but at different times and possibly in different computers, does the code reordering performed by the compiler remains same or it may differ. i.e. does the logic behind code optimization by code reordering depend only on the code or it depends on various other parameters?

The context of the question is that I want to create a tool which finds out whether the two dlls are same or different based on their functionalities.

Comment: I am not sure though, but it might be non-deterministic in a sense that many parameters apart from the source code might affect the compiler output. Like lets say, cpu architecture: e.g. P4 vs core 2 duo.

Answer (score 2):

Correct me if I'm wrong in assuming that since you want to compare dlls based on their functionality, you don't care about implementation details.  Based on this assumption, it is clear that your tool could only look at the function signatures and classes, structs, etc definitions exposed by the dlls which would always be the same regardless of compiler for the same dll.

Comment: Hi, Could you give me some idea on how function signatures, classes, structs etc. can be looked from the dll?

Comment: However, in my case I can't guarantee that if the function signature is identical in both the dlls, they both will have the same functionality or same side effects, so i might need to compare the codes of the function too.